# How can I reduce the sheen of Osmo Polyx hardwax oil?

Tags: hardwood-floor, hardwood-refinishing

I put on a first coat of Polyx on my fir floor. I am regretting the choice of Satin instead of Matte. I can see it is quite shiny already on the harder/denser parts of the boards and I imagine that the softer areas are going get shiny after another coat.

Short of sanding out the first coat I just did and starting fresh with matte, are there ways of dulling the shine on hardwax oils?

Answer (score 1):

I would try lightly sand the first coat (normal anyway to get a key for the second) and then continue with the matte oil for the subsequent coat or coats.

Having to thoroughly sand back the first coat would be more work but likely a surer outcome...